# python - flatten and unpack list

Tags: python, sqlite, flatten

here is some code i have which is really ugly i am hoping someone can show me how to make it better. i vaguely know how to fix this code but can't get any improvements to work in practice.

```
list1 = ([1, 10])
array2 = numpy.ones((1,3))
array3=numpy.ones((1,2))

conn = sqlite3.connect("a.db")
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("insert into a_table values(?, ? , ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (list1[0], list1[1], array2[0][0], array2[0][1], array2[0][2], array3[0][0], array3[0][1]))
```

#

what i think i need to do is append list1, array2 and array3 into a list and then flatten it somehow. and then unpack the entire list into the table with one command somehow... thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

You could use [ravel](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html#numpy-ravel) to make `array2` and `array3` 1-dimensional:

```
In [149]: import itertools

In [150]: list(itertools.chain(list1, array2.ravel(), array3.ravel()))
Out[150]: [1, 10, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1]
```

Comment: you can probably pass the chain generator directly to sqlite3 and not convert it to a list ...

Comment: You cannot pass the generator straight into sqlite3.

Comment: `ravel()` creates a new array.  Why not use the iterator `flat`? `list(itertools.chain(list1, array2.flat, array3.flat))`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: `ravel` does not create a new array in this case. (I think it only create a copy if you change the `order` from `C` to `F` or vice versa.) Though you are right `flat` would have been just as good.

Comment: @unutbu:  Yes.  I should have read the docs for `ravel` more closely: "**A copy is made only if needed.**"

Answer (score 2):

Just built a new list by casting the arrays to single-dimension lists:

```
c.execute("insert into a_table values(?, ? , ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", 
    list1 + list(array2[0]) + list(array3[0]))
```

Alternatively, you could use [`.ravel()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) to create one-dimensional arrays:

```
c.execute("insert into a_table values(?, ? , ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", 
    list1 + list(array2.ravel()) + list(array3.ravel()))
```

If the number of parameters is variable, you can generate the placeholder parameters too:

```
from itertools import chain
params = list(chain(list1, array2.ravel(), array3.ravel()))

c.execute("insert into a_table values(%s)" % (', '.join(('?',) * len(params),),
    params)
```

Comment: Maybe use `array2.ravel()` etc. so that the arrays can be any shape.

Comment: Does sqlite3 accept an iterator?  If so `itertools.chain` could work here.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: it doesn't, unfortunately.

Comment: is there a way to do this without putting in the question marks? my table has many columns so it is burdensome for me to write in each question mark...

Comment: @appleLover: You can generate the placeholders to match the number of parameters; answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> master_l = list(array2)+list(array3)
>>> list1.extend(chain(*master_l)
... )
>>> list1
[1, 10, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]

>>> c.execute("insert into a_table values(?, ? , ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",list1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, if you're not doing this in a loop, itertools.chain() doesn't gain you anything.  Here's something simple based on your input:

```
list1=([1,10])
array2 = numpy.ones((1,3))
array3 = numpy.ones((1,2))

args=list1 + list(*array2) + list(*array3)
# [1, 10, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
conn = sqlite3.connect("a.db")
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("insert into a_table values(?, ? , ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",*args)
```